# Are there any good linux single board computers (sbc) for elliptic key signing, that have zero wireless capabilities?

Tags: linux, sbc

Does anyone know of any (offline, air gapped) single board computers (sbc) that can run linux that have essentially no wireless communication capabilities?
(That is no wifi, bluetooth, nfc, or any other wireless communication)

Pretty sure a nearly perfect (air gapped) elliptic curve signing computer could communicate exclusively with monitors and cameras for QR codes, and has only these communication interface:

- Camera, for scanning QR codes of unsigned messages
- Monitor for showing QR codes of public key and signed messages
- Monitor for interaction (generating new keys, signing, etc.)
- OS drive slot
- Keys drive slot (x4) replica array (usb)
- (usb keyboard slot, usb mouse slot, or touchscreen)

With elliptic curve signing, seems like the best authentication pattern is:

- Write an OS to a drive (ssd, sd, micro sd) from an online computer
- Insert OS in offline computer
- Generate elliptic private and public keys on offline computer
- Scan unsigned messages and public keys with camera
- Show public keys and signed messages to online computer camera with QR code (or similar)

Then for new OS versions, could:

- Install OS to a new empty drive
- Somehow destroy previous drive, either erasing bytes on another offline computer dedicated to erasing, or literally just drilling it or something.
- Insert new OS drive in offline signing computer.

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually just bought a https://libre.computer/products/aml-s905x-cc,

although it does have an IR Receiver,

maybe it doesn't have any wireless transmitters;

I'm not entirely sure.